# Android spinner shows EMPTY values

Tags: android, spinner

I am new in android. I need to fill the spinner from SQLite database.
my layout >> main.xml contains

```
<Spinner 
            android:id="@+id/cmbLocations"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:prompt="@string/location_prompt"
        />

<EditText android:id="@+id/text1" android:layout_width="300dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I have a public function which returns the locations:

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";

public Cursor GetLocations()
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, 
                new String[] 
                { 
                    KEY_ROWID, // "_id"
                    KEY_LOCATION // "location"
                }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

The code which is populating the spinner is :

```
    Spinner cmbLocations = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cmbLocations);
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();

    Cursor cur = db.GetLocations();
    String[] from = new String[]{"_id","location"};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};// I don't know that why text1 is required here

    startManagingCursor(cur);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cur, from, to); 
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
cmbLocations.setAdapter(adapter);
db.close();
```

The issue i am facing is that the spinner controls shows EMPTY locations. For example if i have two locations, Location1 & Location2. The spinner will show two EMPTY locations. If i have 3 locations the spinner will show three EMPTY locations.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
String[] from = new String[]{"_id","location"};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.text2};// I don't know that why text1 is required here
```

`int[] to` is for placing the values from the cursor,you defined in from.. For example,you are fetching _id and location then you would have to specify its destination,here it might be textview.

Comment: He doesn't have a text2 defined.

Comment: It was just an example.He must be getting the idea about what i wanted to say.

Comment: Thanks hiral.
i have replaced the EditText with TextView & now my "from" contains only one column:
String[] from = new String[]{"location"};

But it also not works for me.

Comment: @Yaqub Ahmad: check your database..does it really contains data? Have you inserted data properly to a database_table?

Comment: @Hiral:
Thanks for helping me.
I just removed the spinner, added it again & used the "android.R.id.text1" instead of "R.id.text1" & it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For R.id.text1 to work (instead of android.R.id.text1), there has to be a layout in your resources with TextView with this id: R.id.text1. For example:

**spin_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/field1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/field2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now you can use in the adapter:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
    R.layout.spin_layout, 
    ur_cursor, 
    new String[] {"Field1_in_ur_cursor", "Field2_in_ur_cursor"}, 
    new int[] {R.id.field1, R.id.field2}, 0);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spin_layout);
```

It binds "Field1_in_ur_cursor" to R.id.field1, and "Field2_in_ur_cursor" to R.id.field2 for the spinner with layout spin_layout.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Should your from array just be {"location"}

Have a look here:

[Simple Spinner Item Source](http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/android-r-layout-simple-spinner-item-in-white-t4178.html#p96789)

This shows what the spinner 'simple_spinner_item' is actually doing and it explains what your r.id.text1 is.

Your passing two columns into the Spinner but only wanting to display one.

Print some log's around your Cursor to see if it actually contains data.

Comment: Do you have a column in your DB table called location? Otherwise do what I said and loop round your cursor yourself to see if it actually contains data.

Comment: the column exists.
Actually my code is
if(cur.moveToFirst())
{
   editTeuxtswl.setText(cur.getString(0)); //works fine
   
   //logic for fill spinner
}

Comment: You can't read a cursor twice, I assume you just had that for debug?

Answer (score 0):

I have two columns to show on spinner and when : tried to use code like;

```
String[] from = new String[]{"_id","location"}; 
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.text2};
```

It did not work. when I change it to:

```
String[] from = new String[]{"_id","location"}; 
int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text1};
```

It worked for me.